403 Error code, when i send request to the server with styles enabled in html page
I use Spring Security, i am authorize with ADMIN_ROLE on page. I have "lock user" button on this page and when i press the button, request sends and i get 403 error. Page loads styles from file style.css. And when styles enabled i get error, when i disable styles, i don't get error. Who can help me with it?
Html meta
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Users</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">

Form with patch requset
<form th:action="@{'/users/' + ${user.userId} + '?lock=1'}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
  <button class="page_button" type="submit">Lock user</button>
</form>

Server logs with enabled security trace
2024-05-08T16:12:13.191+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing PATCH /users/a77246cc-3353-4480-936f-d2d6ef9a706d?lock=1
2024-05-08T16:12:13.192+04:00 DEBUG 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for https://localhost:8080/users/a77246cc-3353-4480-936f-d2d6ef9a706d?lock=1
2024-05-08T16:12:13.192+04:00 DEBUG 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
2024-05-08T16:12:13.192+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=
2024-05-08T16:12:13.192+04:00 DEBUG 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error?lock=1
2024-05-08T16:12:13.193+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-05-08T16:12:13.193+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=651448C2F40E52F1E955B65F3CF7ADBC], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-05-08T16:12:13.193+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/16)
2024-05-08T16:12:13.193+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtRequestFilter (14/16)
2024-05-08T16:12:13.193+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtRefreshFilter (15/16)
2024-05-08T16:12:13.193+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (16/16)
2024-05-08T16:12:13.193+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@5168821]]
2024-05-08T16:12:13.193+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@5168821]] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$1886/0x0000022711c49800@7ea871b5
2024-05-08T16:12:13.193+04:00 DEBUG 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error?lock=1
2024-05-08T16:12:13.203+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=
2024-05-08T16:12:13.204+04:00 DEBUG 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /css/style.css
2024-05-08T16:12:13.204+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Found username 'admin@mail.com' in Basic Authorization header
2024-05-08T16:12:13.204+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-05-08T16:12:13.204+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.account_is_locked,u1_0.account_is_enabled,u1_0.password,u1_0.user_id from users_table u1_0 where u1_0.email=?
Hibernate: select r1_0.id,r1_1.role_id,r1_1.role_name from role_user r1_0 join roles_table r1_1 on r1_1.role_id=r1_0.role_id where r1_0.id=?
2024-05-08T16:12:13.480+04:00 DEBUG 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2024-05-08T16:12:13.480+04:00 DEBUG 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] .s.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy : Changed session id from 651448C2F40E52F1E955B65F3CF7ADBC
2024-05-08T16:12:13.481+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Preparing session with CsrfAuthenticationStrategy (2/2)
2024-05-08T16:12:13.481+04:00 DEBUG 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy  : Replaced CSRF Token
2024-05-08T16:12:13.481+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/16)
2024-05-08T16:12:13.481+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtRequestFilter (14/16)
2024-05-08T16:12:13.481+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtRefreshFilter (15/16)
2024-05-08T16:12:13.481+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (16/16)
2024-05-08T16:12:13.481+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@2102ea33]
2024-05-08T16:12:13.481+04:00 TRACE 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@2102ea33] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$1886/0x0000022711c49800@7ea871bz
2024-05-08T16:12:13.481+04:00 DEBUG 103408 --- [fin-man-api] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /css/style.css

I tried adding "/css/style.css" in permitAll requests, turning off CSRF for "/css/style.css", and many other options, but nothing helped.
 http
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer
                        .ignoringRequestMatchers(disabledCsrfUrl))
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .with(jwtAuthenticationConfigurer, Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/error", HttpMethod.GET.name()).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/registration", HttpMethod.POST.name()).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,getUrl).hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER", "MODERATOR")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, postUrl).hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER", "MODERATOR")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, deleteUrl).hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER", "MODERATOR")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, patchUrl).hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER", "MODERATOR")
                        .requestMatchers(moderatorUrl).hasAnyRole("ADMIN","MODERATOR")
                        .requestMatchers(adminUrl).hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .headers(headers -> headers
                        .frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable)
                        .xssProtection(HeadersConfigurer.XXssConfig::disable));

        return http.build();


You should use wildcard pattern for intercepting URLs. Create a separate folder for styles, JavaScript, and images. Then update your https security service like this
<http>
     <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
     <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
     <intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" />



I also tried this, only CSRF disabled works

CRSF disabled for this url paths (/css/, /js/, /img/** )

i added my security config higher

When you submit a button the action is invoked and it requests the security to get access to that url, but this url is not configured in your configuration, and you can't access it without authentication. Also I don't see error with the code 403 in your logs.
